# Как найти метки без описания?

Tags: поддержка, метки, описание-метки, статистика, data-explorer

Я тут решил опять заняться вопросом чистки меток и стало мне интересно, как найти метки у которых нет краткого описания. (Можно и полного, но в первую очередь посетителям видны именно краткие описания)

Как это можно сделать? И как вообще получить полный список меток, чтобы хотя бы руками их прокликать?

Answer (score 4):

https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/978990/tags-without-short-description

```
SELECT T.Id
     , tagname
     , concat('site://','tags/', T.TagName, '/info|', T.tagname) [Tag info Page]
     , p.body
FROM tags t
left outer JOIN posts AS p
ON P.Id = T.ExcerptPostId
WHERE p.id is null
or len(p.body) = 0
```

Только не забывайте, что на DSE данные раз в неделю обновляются.

**P.S.** спасибо @rene за помощь (:

Comment: Sorry, to do this in English: You need an outer join to get all tags without an excerpt:  https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/978990/tags-without-short-description

Comment: @rene thanks! I've updated the answer.

Comment: 10144 метки, ничего себе... А сколько их вообще? Что-то мне кажется, вообще смысл использования меток при таком их количестве теряется.

Comment: @avp на основном сайте никогда метками не пользуюсь. На мете довольно удобно искать, т.к. тут активные участники в порядке метки держат.

Comment: Да, на Мете всего (?) 303 метки. Я все равно  не представляю (как и с самого начала на Хэшкоде, тоже не понимал), какая от них польза.

Comment: @avp у нас не так много вопросов за день, можно просто все новые просмотреть. А вот на SOen слишком много вопросов, поэтому люди добавляют какие-то метки в избранное и уже по ним поиск делают.

Comment: Тогда логично было бы автоматически удалять все метки на которые никто не подписался в течении T дней после создания метки.

Comment: @avp а если у вопроса все метки такие? По правилам на вопросе должна быть хотя бы одна метка. Вопрос тоже удалять? (:

Comment: Вопрос удалять не надо. А вот систему стоит перепроектировать.

Comment: @avp боюсь, такие фундаментальные вещи уже не поправить.

Comment: Я тоже так думаю, пусть живет как получится.....

Comment: Кстати, поигрался с SQL и понял, что ошибся. Всего у нас 4449 меток, из них 3162 без описания. Впрочем, принципиально картину это не меняет.

Comment: @avp метки, по которым нет вопросов, автоматически удаляются только через месяц.